# Software recommendation for drawing atomic structures

Tags: software, software-recommendations, visualization-software, structure

Anyone familiar what kind of software is used for drawing the atomic strucutres shown in the attached figure?
[image]

Comment: This looks very similar to the ones generated from YAeHMOP package. It has a gui that can generate images and the structures did have this aesthetic.

Comment: I use VESTA and VMD often, but I assume you know of these. They don't make drawings just like that, but they make good ones!

Comment: Are you willing to draw your own structures or to visualize?

Comment: @Camps, I am fine with both options, a visuzlization software would be much straightforward, but if not available, I could go with drawing one.

Comment: @TylerSterling. Thank you for the comment, I do use VESTA but this time I am willing to have something different

Comment: @HemanthHaridas. Thank you, I will check that package.